# while looping in c language iteration

Tags: c

I don't know where is my mistake, please I need your help. When I enter a wrong data in my username and password and it will ask if YES or NO to try again. If I type Y as a YES I can't type in username anymore.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {  
    printf ("\n\t\t  Welcome To Your Payroll Account!");
    printf ("\n\t\t  Please Enter Your Username & Password To Proceed.");
    printf ("\n\t ********************************************************* \n \n \n");

    char password [10], username [10], ch;
    char name [10] = "username";
    char pass[10] = "password";

    char month, ename, address;
    float regpay,regov,RD,RDOT,meal;
    float SSS,PH,PI,Union,other,SSSsal,Loan,Hloan,ULoan,ELoan,TD;
    float TE,Netpay;
    int n,day,year,i;
    char input;
    char again = 'Y';

    while (again == 'Y' || again =='y') {
        printf("Username: ");
        gets (username);

        printf("Password: ");    

        for (i = 0; i<8; i++){
            ch = getch();
            password[i] = ch;
            printf ("*");
        }

        password[i] = 0;
        printf("\n Your password is: ");

        for (i =0; i<8; i++) {
            printf("%c", password[i]);    
        } 

        if(strcmp(pass,password) == 0 && strcmp(name,username) == 0) {
            printf("\n \n You are logged in! \n");
            printf("Enter # to proceed \n");
            scanf("%c", &input);    
        } else {
            printf("\n \n Incorrect username or password");
            printf("\n\n Do you want to try again? YES(Y) / NO(N) \n");
            printf("Continue? ");
            scanf("%c", &again);
            again;

        if (again == 'N' || again == 'n') {
            system ("pause");
            return 0;
        } else {
            again;      
        } 
   }  
}

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: okay thanks for that. but still the same can you help me?

Comment: @Bryan: help was given — no, SO is not a coding service and you are expected to do some of the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    printf("Continue? ");
    scanf("%c", &again);
    again;

if (again == 'N' || again == 'n') {
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
} else {
    again;      
}
```

Here while taking char input you are using scanf()

so will give character input plus enter.
again will get the input character, but enter will remains in buffer.

When while loop iterates, gets which is waiting for username input will get enter character automatically from the buffer, so the username input will be skipped.

solution is to add getch() after

```
scanf("%c", &again);
```

Hope this will hep you.